# Any listener is possible in if condition

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

i do for this code but not supported for ths issue and what i do for solution this like as if codition inside any listener.

```
if (btn.isEnabled()) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: No. It is not possible to understand your question.

Comment: That's right.  Any listener is possible in if condition.

Comment: yes button that listener will execute only when condition is true otherwise it will execute that listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But why???

any button's onClickListener will only be called if its "enabled".
You dont need to bother about onClickListeners which are assigned to disabledButtons.

suppose your button is disabled at the launch of activity then this listener wont be applied to your button.
Now after some time if you enable this button (may be after some event etc.) 
"THEN ALSO THIS LISTENER WONT WORK" as you did not set the listener at the first place...

so IMO dont put that in if...

Answer (score 0):

this code successfully.

```
if (button.isEnabled()) {
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", 10).show();
                }
            });
        }
```